# Who was the third character in 10.000km?

Tags: character, 10000-km

The film [*10.000km*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3114132/) (AKA *Long Distance*) is about a couple with a long-distance relationship between Barcelona and Los Angeles. It is almost entirely shot in two apartments, and throughout the film I've noticed that there are only two actors.  There aren't even any walk-ons.

I was surprised, therefore to see that IMDB lists a *third* actor, Sirius Flatz as a "Friend of Alex".

[image]

**In what scene of the film do we see or hear him or her?**

Comment: Apparently she is preparing a dinner with her friends, but I don't recall what exactly we see or hear during the movie.

Comment: @fedorqui - He's not in that scene. She's on her own there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that only two actors are seen on set and there are only two names in the actual [film credits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQ2B.png).

[Sirius Flatz](https://twitter.com/SiriusFlatz/photo) was one of Alex's friends visible ***in a photo on her Facebook page***. He and the others are listed in the crew credits as;

> **Apariciones Especiales: Amigos Alex.**
> *<sup>(Special Appearances: Friends of Alex)</sup>*
>
> [image]
> <sub><sup>**Timestamp 1:00:01**</sup></sub>

Mr Flatz is the guy on the right with the black heart-shaped sunglassed.

> [image]